# Is the boost::variant visitor class a requirement?

Tags: c++, boost-variant, apply-visitor

Am I required to use a visitor class such as `class Visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>` with boost::variant?

If not, are there reasons not to use a visitor?  Are there reasons to prefer a visitor class?

I ask this question because a visitor class appears a redundant aspect to the use of boost::variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not forced to use a visitor, you can perfectly query for the underlying type using `get<T>()`.

This leads to such code:

```
int foo(boost::variant<int, std::string, Bar> const& v) {
    if (int const* i = get<int>(&v)) {
        return *i;
    }
    if (std::string const* s = get<std::string>(&v)) {
        return boost::lexical_cast<int>(*s);
    }
    if (Bar const* b = get<Bar>(&v)) {
        return b->toInt();
    }

    std::abort(); // ?
}
```

Which is, arguably, ugly... and furthermore has the issue that should you add one type to the variant suddenly you need to inspect every single use of it in the code to check you are not missing a `if` somewhere.

On the other hand, should you be using a variant, if you ever fail to handle a case (type) you will be notified with a compile-time error.

In my eyes, using `boost::static_visitor` is infinitely superior... though I have used the `get<T>()` alternative a couple times; generally when I only need to check one (or two) types and do not care (at all) about all the others. An alternative would be using a visitor with a `template <typename T> void operator()(T const&) const;` overload, which is not necessarily cleaner.

Comment: Could I not simply query for the underlying type using `SomeVariantVariable.which()` that will return an index to a `typedef boost::variant<Type1, Type2> variant_variable` declaration and indicate which type: Type1 = 0, Type2 = 1?

Comment: @Mushy: you can yes, and then `switch` on that and call `get()`; but at this point you are just reimplementing the code that's calling a Visitor... except that if anyone adds a type in the middle of the list then the indexes shift, and thus `get()` might return null which you have to account for (or crash).

Answer (score 0):

If want to have some operation on variant, for example some check, than you may want to have it as visitor.

```
struct to_str : boost::static_visitor<std::string>
{
   template<class T>
   std::string operator()(T const & x) const
   {
      return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x);
   }
};
```

On the other hand if you want, for example check if it `int` and do something with it, you would probably use `boost::get` e.g.

```
if(const int * my_int = boost::get<int>(&my_var)) //no-throw form
{
  //do smth with int
}
```